# How can change symbols in Tradingview with JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, tradingview-api

How can change symbols in input dom in tradingview website with js. For create chrome-extension
link: https://www.tradingview.com/chart/ET5o8tNl/

Its no have enter button but if you manual type symbols on UI it automatic change
but I wonder how I change it with code. Any Idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating your widget inside your code, it accepts an options object.
One of the keys inside the options is symbol, with which you can change the symbol passed to your chart:

```
const widgetOptions = {
  symbol: yourDesiredSymbol, // here you can pass your own symbol
  ...other options can be added here
}

const yourWidget = new widget(widgetOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been grappling with this issue for quite some time, but I've finally figured it out. The solution is:

```
TradingViewApi._studyMarket._chartWidgetCollection.setSymbol('BINANCE:SOLUSDT.P')
```